# Родительские отступы

Tags: html

Как у `<img>` убрать родительские отступы (левый и правый)?
Т.е. я изображение вытягиваю на 100% и центрирую

```
/*CSS*/
#center {text-align:center}
/*HTML*/
<div id="center"><img src="...." width="100%"></div>
```

И при просмотре страницы слева и справа у изображения появляются родительские отступы.

Comment: @LiveStreet, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/6ow2aLyc/

HTML

```
<div>
    <img src="http://cs618130.vk.me/v618130675/100fb/8TIlaGxPkus.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

div{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;    
}
div img{
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`margin: 0` and `padding: 0`;

Answer (score 0):

Этот кусок кода поможет от всех проблем с img:

```
img {
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```